# Automatically play audio in HTML 5

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have music I want to play and loop on the web page startup. Here's my code:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay"  loop controls="controls"> 
  <source src="music.mp3" />  
</audio>
```

The question that is a "duplicate" does not suit my needs and does not work for me.

Comment: Can anyone else see the code? I cant see it on my end.

Comment: Can not see your code.

Comment: To loop you can add the `loop` attribute to your `audio` tag. Does your console say anything? (If the file cannot be loaded it will be shown there.)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Thanks for that, I will rename the file and see if it changes

Answer (score 1):

I found out what to do using a div with the visibility to hidden

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<audio controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
```